# How to make the slider of a Tkinter scale vary between similar values on the two ends?

Tags: python, tkinter, scale

How can we have a Tkinter scale move from two equal scales? For example, as shown on the picture below, I am trying to get 9 to 0 and 9 again instead of -9.

i.e. a balance scale around 0 where both ends are +9.

Like this -> 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

[image]

Is it possible to do this with scale otherwise which widget can I use for this?

Comment: This seems like it would be very confusing to a user. How would the software know that you picked the left 9 or the right 9, since in both cases the value is just 9.

Comment: Well, there are two labels on the two sides of the scaler (like apple and orange). The idea is to let the user pick which one they favor the most by comparing the two. If they favor right, they give +9 to right and vice versa. Also, in terms of implementation, I am fine to have 9 to -9 (so that I can figure our left and right) but I would like to display the label as 9 to 0  to 9 if possible.